# when is `dconf dump` and `dconf load` not inverse?

Tags: dconf

I use `dconf dump /` and `dconf load /` to keep configurations in sync.  This usually works, but I observe that sometimes there is a discrepancy that the result of dump is not what was loaded before:

```
frank@gabun:~$ dconf load / < dump5
frank@gabun:~$ dconf dump / > dump11
```

should produce a file `dump11` which is exactly the same as `dump5` (and in many instance is) but in this instance the two are different, without a warning or error report. What are the reasons that load and dump   is not inverse? When must I expect a difference?

The observations are made on a Debian buster and a corresponding Ubuntu 20.10 installation with libconf1 0.30.1-2 respectively 0.38.0-1.

I show here the difference between the two files:

```
frank@gabun:~$ diff dump5 dump11
165a166,167
> autoar-filter='none'
> autoar-format='zip'
233a236,239
> [org/gnome/nm-applet/eap/06ba9272-4479-41c9-8fd5-be7f3cfbb8f9]
> ignore-ca-cert=false
> ignore-phase2-ca-cert=false
> 
517a524,529
> [org/mate/panel/objects/object-17]
> launcher-location='/usr/share/applications/vivaldi-stable.desktop'
> object-type='launcher'
> panel-right-stick=false
> position=452
> toplevel-id='top'
677a690
> backspace-binding='ascii-del'
678a692
> delete-binding='escape-sequence'
```

Note: I have removed vivaldi-stable from the installed programs.

I found that loading an empty file has no effect

```
dconf dump / > dump1
touch dump0 
dconf load / < dump0 
dconf dump0 / > dump2  # should be the same, is not
diff dump2 dump0  # should be the same, is not
diff dump2 dump1  # this is the same!
```